Multiple Imputation for missing outcomes in Cox regression
Imagine an RCT with a time-to-event outcome which is analyzed using a Cox regression. There are four assessments (T1=before randomization, T2=3 weeks, T3=6 weeks, T4=12 weeks). Under the censoring at random assumption, correct inferences are made regarding early uninformative drop-outs (e.g., drop-out after assessment T2). Now there‘s a special case for those who drop-out: Those who immediately drop-out of the study after randomization (i.e., only T1 is known). If we control for baseline covariates in our final Cox model, which are available for each participant (also those who dropped out after T1), then
is it recommended:

to impute the outcome data (Event and time until Event) for the special case of no outcome data at all (i.e., only for those having only T1 data)
to impute the outcome data for all cases of missing outcomes before end of study (also those cases missing at T2, T3 or T4), neglecting the inherent censoring mechanism of Cox regression
to use a complete case analysis?

Any recommendations?

CCA can mean canonical correspondence analysis -- just not here. Otherwise Sir David Cox deserves his capital, a small point which I feel keenly.

Where did you see a recommendation to impute outcome data?  Imputation is used to create placeholders so that non-missing data are not excluded from analysis.  Imputation does not recover information that was lost except in the rare case of having a surrogate endpoint that is used to approximate a real endpoint.  The random censoring assumption already buys you an optimum analysis by recognizing that some observations are right-censored.  And an observation that is censored at time zero is effectively completely ignored in the survival time regression analysis.
Never use a complete case analysis that drops observations that are censored later than time zero.

Thanks a lot, Frank Harrell. In my case a reviewer asked for an ITT analysis (which should be an imputation based analysis or how else should I do ITT?). I do not have data after randomization for 19% of participants in each group.  If I understand your recommendation correctly, an ITT analysis doesnt make sense and I should argue against such an analysis?

What makes you say an "ITT analysis" doesn't make sense? To be fair, the term "ITT analysis" is pretty vague and unclear, which is why we use the estimand terminology nowadays to be more specific of exactly what we are trying to do.

In my understanding, ITT should include ALL randomized subjects in the analysis. This mainly refers to having 1) the “correct” intervention according to randomized group and 2) drop-outs. I do not have any problem with 1). But for 2) drop-outs, the only thing I can think of is using MI to impute the outcomes for those who drop-out without any post-randomization data.

If I used censoring of these individuals at t=0, then, as Frank Harrell pointed out, I effectively would have a “complete case analysis” (in this case this is any person for whom I have post-randomization data, even if censored before end of study (right-censoring), I do not know of a better word than CCA with right-censoring, maybe someone can help) as the risk set only reduces after t=0. I’m not conducting a regulatory trial, but ICH E9 may offer a solution: The FAS (full analysis set) is “as complete as possible and as close as possible to ITT ideal of including all randomised subjects”.

In my opinion, without using outcome imputation this is the way to go. If I used the FAS (=excluding only those participants for whom I do not have post-randomization data), then my power is reduced and bias is induced if there are different reasons for drop-out between randomized groups. However, I used the Jackson imputation (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25060703/) to account for censoring not at random, where I accounted for different log hazard ratios between the uncensored and censored individuals.

In this sensitivity analysis, I could include those dropping out after randomization, and could observe the robustness of results depending on their probability of having an event. I think this is one of the most robust ways to handle my missing data problem but would be happy to have your thoughts on that. Maybe I miss something or there are alternative (better?) ways

What is the question you are trying to answer? E.g. if those that drop-out stop their randomized study drug and you assume that the treatment effect goes away immediately, are you interested in

what would have happened, if they had hypothetically not stopped the treatment,
what would have happened, if they had been followed to the end of the study (off treatment), or
some other questions?

Depending on your answer, what you should do differs. If you want to to do the first thing, then if you are willing to rely on censoring (including at time 0 [= no contribution to the analysis] for those that are not followed at all after randomization) to be random (conditional on the model terms in your time-to-even model - i.e. dropping out must not depend on other things, e.g. if you have an analysis model without further covariates and older patients get more side effects on treatment and drop-out more, but also have a worse prognosis, you have a problem), you don't need to explicitly impute. If you want to address this question, but relax the assumptions made, you may have to impute. If you want to do the second thing, you likely would go with some imputation approach.
The one thing I cannot see a good reason to ever use would be a complete-case analysis (I kind of assume you'd still include patients that are administratively censored at the foreseen study end, because otherwise you'd guarantee 100% with an event in all treatment groups). It is really hard to come up with any real question that would be answered by that analysis.

Thanks, Björn. I added more details in the comments to Frank Harrell‘s answer. I would like to estimate the „real world“ effectiveness of my intervention. I do not know whether patients stopped intervention usage after drop-out. My concern is that I do not have post-randomization data and thus have to exclude these participants. If this was unrelated to the outcome, I‘d only suffer from loss of power, but if it indeed is related to the outcome, I‘d bias the analysis (thats probably what you meant with some imputation approach, accounting for MNAR?)

It‘d be also of interest what kind of question would be answered if these participants without outcome data were censored at t=0 as you proposed. Then, in case of CAR/MAR, I‘d only suffer from loss of power, is that correct (as these individuals are dropped from analysis/the risk set). And in case of bias (MNAR/CNAR) I could do sensitivity analyses

"do not have post-randomization data & thus have to exclude these participants" - you don't have to. What you do must depend on the circumstances & the question you're asking. E.g. in a RCT of drug vs. placebo & no blinding, you might have patients with the worst prognosis quit the placebo group ("I'm so sick and I'm getting placebo? No way, I'm out!") & cases with good prognosis quit the treatment group ("I was probably going to be fine anyway, and now I get this stuff with potential side effects?"). That's a serious bias & just treating as censored/excluding doesn't cut it.

Excluding patients without follow-up is fine if it has no connection at all with outcomes (it's not CAR/MAR, but CCAR/MCAR, i.e. completely at random). The moment it has a connection (and to be honest the possibility it could have can never be totally excluded), it's at least a theoretical concern. You can of course hope that the practical impact is limited. You do have to make assumptions for what happens after the last follow-up, in a RCT of a new drug, you often know patients cannot take it after dropping out (because how would they get it), but they might take something else instead.
